# Filebeat beats_input_raw_event, what is it?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, filebeat

I am running filebeat on a k8s cluster, and I see this a lot in the index:

```
      {
    "_index": "filebeat-6.8.0-2019.06.10",
    "_type": "doc",
    "_id": "Hgh5QWsBDoVggnwmKIVx",
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {
      "@version": "1",
      "tags": [
        "beats_input_raw_event"
      ],
      "@timestamp": "2019-06-10T12:59:46.250Z"
    }
```

I'm not sure  where or how this document is created? Can someone shed some light on this please?

I've tried stopping my application from creating log statements, but this message is till generated.

Comment: It's not clear what is expected to do with this description. In addition it seems it's expected behavior related to your specific [configuration](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/beats-input-raw-event/130391)
So please refer to the official [filebeat documenation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/configuration-logging.html)